# jQuery grep doesn't work with element attribute?

Tags: jquery, grep

I'm seeing some interesting behavior with `grep`...

```
// where gon.items = array of objects with various properties, one of which is id
var id = $(this).data("id")
var inventory_item = $.grep(gon.items, function(e){ return e.id == id })[0]
=> successfully retrieves object

var inventory_item = $.grep(gon.items, function(e){ return e.id == ($(this).data("id")) })[0]
=> []
```

As you can see the only difference is that in the first successful code I defined a separate id variable. Why does `grep` require that and not allow me to pass the element attribute? Or what am I doing wrong? I could not find an explanation in the docs.

Comment: `console.log($(this))` and see if that is what it is referring!!

Comment: What is $(this) inside the $.grep ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unlike many jQuery functions, `jQuery.grep()` doesn't change the context of `this` to be the current item being iterated. Actually, inside the `grep` callback, `this` keeps it's global context, and in a browser will refer to the `window` object. So most likely `$(this).data("id") === undefined`.

Here's a quick snippet that demonstrates this:

```js
var g = [1, 2, 3];
$.grep(g, function(item) {
  console.log(this === window);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you're working with a collection of jQuery elements, you probably want to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead, which will provide the behavior you are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

That is because of context. When you pass a function to `$.grep`, the context `this` inside that function will be `window`.

You can control that and `.bind` a different context like so:

```
var inventory_item = $.grep(gon.items, function(e){ return e.id == $(this).data("id") }.bind(this))[0]
```